# Samsung Smart TV popup list input

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I want to make a listinput popup just like Samsung has in their documentation:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/User_Experience_Guideline_1.5/Extra_Features/Policy_on_popup_windows/Action_Window

Like this:

[image: description image]

but there is no information on how to implement this.

**Here's a sample code I found:**

```
 $('#newName_popup').sfPopup({
      text: 'Enter your name',
      buttons: ['Ok', 'Cancel'],
      timeout: 0,
      defaultFocus: 0, 
      callback: function newNameCallback(selectedIndex){
           alert('popup_callback');
           if(selectedIndex == 0){
                alert();
           }
      }
 });
```

How do I find names of all the properties (text, buttons, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up trying to change the input Samsung provides instead I made a small scene with transparent black background:

**Starting the scene:**

```
sf.scene.show('CityPopup');
sf.scene.focus('CityPopup');
```

**Hiding scene:**

```
sf.scene.show('Scene1');
sf.scene.hide('CityPopup');
sf.scene.focus('Scene1');
```

**scene background:**

```
background : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
```